# Date formatted cell in xlsx files to R

Tags: r, date, xlsx

I have an excel file which has date information in some cells. like :
[image]

I read this file into R by the following command :

```
library(xlsx)

data.files = list.files(pattern = "*.xlsx")
data <- lapply(data.files, function(x) read.xlsx(x, sheetIndex = 9,header = T))
```

Everything is correct except the cells with date! instead of having the xlsx information into those cell, I always have  `42948` as a date :
[image]

Does anybody know how could I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, after importing your files, dates are represented as numeric values (here `42948`). They are actually the internal representation of the date information in Excel. Those values are the ones that R presents instead of the “real” dates.

You can get those dates in R with `as.Date(42948 - 25569, origin = "1970-01-01")`

Notice that you can also use a vector containing the internal representation of the dates, so this should also work

```
vect <- c(42948, 42949, 42950)
as.Date(vect - 25569, origin = "1970-01-01")
```

PS: To convert an Excel datetime colum, see [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xlsx/xlsx.pdf) (p.31)