# Dates out by 2 days when I convert to Date Format in R

Tags: r, date

When I am converting dates from characters to "dates" it seems to be off by 2 days from excel?

My example

```
mydata <- c(38808,40422,40493,40606)
as.Date(mydata, origin="1900-01-01")
# [1] "2006-04-03" "2010-09-03" "2010-11-13" "2011-03-06"
```

yet in excel the dates are as follows

```
Date    in Excel    in R    Delta
38808   2006-04-01  2006-04-03  2
40422   2010-09-01  2010-09-03  2
40493   2010-11-11  2010-11-13  2
40606   2011-03-04  2011-03-06  2
```

I get around it by changing origin date to 1899-12-30 but I am sure I am doing something wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46469727/date-formatted-cell-in-xlsx-files-to-r/46470782#46470782

Comment: See the Other Applications section of the R Help Desk article in https://www.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2004-1.pdf

Answer (score 2):

It is a known problem that Excel thinks 1900 was a leap year, but it was not.  So Excel counts an extra day (for nonexistent Feb 29, 1900).  In addition,  Excel considers "1900-01-01" as day 1, not day 0.

Maybe the link will help:
http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datetime.htm

Answer (score 0):

For excel dates you need this one:

```
mydata <- c(38808,40422,40493,40606)
 as.Date(mydata, origin = "1899-12-30")
[1] "2006-04-01" "2010-09-01" "2010-11-11" "2011-03-04"
```